# 'Software & Updates' is installed but don't start

Tags: software-installation, updates, 20.04

I installed ubuntu 20.04 two weeks ago from 19.10 using command line.
Now 'discover', 'Show applications' and 'application finder' show that
it's installed but can't start anywhere and it don't inform of any error.
I also tried to remove it and install it again with similar results.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1231557/968501