# How do you get new software on 20.04? The update took out the software app for approved software center

Tags: 20.04, updates, software-center

I got 20.04.1 and was able to add some software back like gparted and FreeCAD. Then I ran the software update (all 500+ MB worth took 2 nights and 2 passes) but now the Software center is gone! What is up? Do I need to get 18.04?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. How do we know what is the problem?

Comment: We can only guess at your problem, as you've provided few clues. My guess is you added a 3rd party source, that wasn't very wise, added some packages that caused conflict with existing packages, the package manager fixed the conflict by removing packages.. but that's pure guess. The fix is to add packages appropriate for your 20.04/focal system. We don't know what you did, can't read your package logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log` etc), read command `history` and possibly most importantly view your sources. We can only guess from the little you provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Comment: Reinstall the software center with `sudo apt install gnome-software`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reinstall Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231557/how-do-i-reinstall-ubuntu-software-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-version)