# GNOME Software Memory Leak

Tags: memory-usage, gnome-software

GNOME Software is memory hog

- GNOME 3.38.1
- GNOME Software 3.38.0
- Ubuntu 20.10
- Linux Kernel 5.8.0-40-generic

[image: System Resource Usage]

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reinstall Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231557/how-do-i-reinstall-ubuntu-software-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-version)

Comment: use `ubuntu-software` instead.

Comment: It is using 45 MB for me right after startup.