# Software centre "Ubuntu Software" not loading correctly

Tags: 20.04, software-center

New to Ubuntu but reasonably PC savvy, been following others attempts to fix the new Ubuntu version of the software center titled "Ubuntu Software" regarding its failure to load little else than the editors pics and having very little luck.

Ubuntu 20.04.2

In short, the Ubuntu software program doesn't load correctly.

followed terminal commands to refresh and reinstall etc etc but like others mentioned this fixed the issue but only temporarily where closing the terminal ends the "fixing" process and reverts the software center back to only loading partly.

The Ubuntu Software also does not display programs which are already installed as well as the explore page after closing the terminal.

Please, has anyone found a more reliable/permanent fix for this seemingly common issue of the software center loading up but not displaying correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reinstall Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231557/how-do-i-reinstall-ubuntu-software-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-version)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)