# Make Ubuntu Software Center the default manager again

Tags: software-center, flatpak, gnome-software

I followed a guide for adding Flatpak support to Ubuntu but now GNOME Software, needed for actually installing the programs, has become the default software manager so, for example, if I click an app's 'show details', GNOME Software is started instead of USC.
How can I set USC as the default software manager again?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Removing `gnome-software` (and if you removed it, reinstalling snap-store) probably will do the trick.

Comment: You may need to reinstall the preferred source. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231562/1222991) will show you how 

Comment: Thank you. Tried re-installing it but couldn't find ubuntu-software. Weird...
Before I proceed with clean installation, are you sure this is how USC is currently named? I tried to find something similar with Synaptics but every "software" reference pointed to GNOME

Comment: Software Centre is a Snap Package. You can't use apt to remove or install it. You have to use `snap`. For eg:- to remove it you've to run `sudo snap remove snap-store` and to install it: `sudo snap install snap-store`

Comment: Thank you, but isn't snap-store a component of the Ubuntu Software Center? Snap-removing ubuntu-software found nothing.